# problem on continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function on $I=[a,b]$ such that for each $x$ in $I$ there exists $y$ in $I$ such that $\lvert f(y)\rvert$$\le\frac{1}{2}\lvert f(x)\rvert$. Show that there exists a point $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Comment: What work have you done so far on this problem?

Comment: @Ispil:i have obtained a sequence such that $\lvert f(x_k)\rvert\le\frac{1}{2}\lvert f(x_{k-1})\rvert$

Comment: or equivalently  $\lvert f(x_k)\rvert\le\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\lvert f(x_1)\rvert$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If f is not identically 0 in $[a,b]$ then there is a point $x_0$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert >0$.

Now define $x_n$ for all $n$ as follows:

Define $x_{n+1}$ as the y in your question when $x=x_n$, i.e. $$\lvert f(x_{n+1})\rvert \leq\frac{1}{2}\lvert f(x_n)\rvert$$

Then $$\lvert f(x_{n})\rvert \leq\frac{1}{2^n}\lvert f(x_0)\rvert$$

So, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)=0$

But $x_n$ is a bounded sequence and hence has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ (say) with limit $l$. Then  $$f(l)=f(\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_{n_k})=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(x_{n_k})=0$$.

Hence $l$ is the required point.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_0\in I$. Let $x_1\in I$ be such that $\bigl|f(x_1)\bigr|\leqslant\frac12\bigl|f(x_0)\bigr|$. Let $x_2\in I$ be such that $\bigl|f(x_2)\bigr|\leqslant\frac12\bigl|f(x_1)\bigr|$, and so on. Of course $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}f(x_n)=0$, and therefore the same thing happens to any subsequence. But, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergente subsequence. So, if $c$ is the limit of this subsequence, $f(c)=0$.

By the way, this has nothing to do with the intermediate value property.